# Function after all Ajax forms on page have been submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a function which submits multiple forms on a page using Ajax.

I am trying to call a function which only actions when all the forms have been submitted.

If I place the function (i.e alert('Done')') inside the script below it of course creates an alert for every form submitted on the page as it's inside the for.each.

I'm trying to only get it to alert once ALL forms have been submitted.

Any tips?

```
$('.order-expire').each(function() {

var form = $('.order-expire');

form.ajaxForm({
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#set-expiry-dates").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#form-loader").show();
    },
    success : function (jsonData) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#set-expiry-dates").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#set-expiry-dates").remove();
             $("#form-loader").hide();
            alert('Done');
        }, 500)
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be better to send the data from all the forms in a single request

Comment: If you must do it this way, why not set a counter to the length of the `$('.order-expire')` selector that is decreased upon each AJAX success call.  Once you're at 0, do your alert logic.

Comment: Your code is flawed. you're applying the ajaxForm method to every form n times.

Comment: OK @KevinB - how do you submit data for all forms in 1 single request?

Comment: using ajaxForm, you would have to turn them all into a single form. I would instead not use ajaxForm and build the ajax myself.

Answer (score 0):

you could check with `.size()` or `.length()` how many forms you got left to loop in your each loop so when it comes to 0 you can trigger the function.

something like:

```
$(".form").each(function(){

//your ajax blah blah

if(!$(this).length()){//0 is a falsie value so if its diferent from 0 it will be truish

alert("OK, IM FINISH BITCHESS!")
}
});
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for this. That doesn't seem to be working though!

Comment: yes you are right, i missed big time...the length method doesent act like a count in the each loop...it would be convinient but it doesent work like that...
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8pBeK/) you have the "manual" way

Answer (score 0):

have u tried?

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  console.log("finished ajax requests")
});
```

hope that helps!